# raw input with conditionals python

Tags: python, raw-input, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a simple quiz for some students and I want the question to repeat if they type the wrong letter, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. Can someone help?

```
player score=[]

x2=raw_input("Question 3" '\n'

"How many tests have you taken in past 24 hours?" '\n'

"A) 0" '\n'

"B) 1" '\n'

"C) 2" '\n'

"D) 3" '\n'

"E) Too many to count"'\n')



if x2=="A":

    player_score.append('0')

elif x2=="B":

    player_score.append('1')

elif x2=="C":

    player_score.append('2')

elif x2=="D":

    player_score.append('3')

elif x2=="E":

    player_score.append('4')

else:

    print "you typed the wrong letter"

print player_score
```

Comment: First -- you might want to mark this 'assistance with homework'?  Second, if you want to loop, then you will need to ADD a loop.

Comment: @user590028: we don't tag questions with homework status anymore (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)).

Comment: Why is player_score a list rather than just a string/integer?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best way of ensuring proper input (and re-prompting if the input is improper) is to use loops. In this case, let's do a `while` loop.

```
player_score = []

answer = ''

while answer.casefold() not in ('a','b','c','d','e'):
    answer = raw_input("Question 3" "\n"
    # etc etc etc
```

That said, it looks like you're building a quiz, so there may be a better way to go about this. I'm assuming the answers will be same for every question (`"A" == 0`, `"B" == 1`, `"C" == 2`, `"D" == 3`, `"E"==4`) so let's do this instead....

```
questions = [
"""Question 3
How many tests have you taken in past 24 hours?
A) 0
B) 1
C) 2
D) 3
E) Too many to count""",

"""Question 4
What kind of question should you write here?
A) I don't know
B) No bloomin' idea
C) It escapes me
D) Foobar
E) One with a question mark?"""]

player_score = []
for question in questions:
    answer = ''
    while answer.casefold() not in ('a','b','c','d','e'):
        answer = raw_input(question+"\n>>")
        answer = answer.casefold()
        if answer == 'a': player_score.append(0)
        if answer == 'b': player_score.append(1)
        if answer == 'c': player_score.append(2)
        if answer == 'd': player_score.append(3)
        if answer == 'e': player_score.append(4)
        else: print("Invalid response")
```

Comment: Since when does `None` have a `casefold` method? ;^)

Comment: @DSM they added it in Python4.11. I have the super-early development version (fixed)

Comment: Does string have a casefold method? (Not in python 2.7...) :s

Comment: @AndyHayden `str.casefold` was added in Python3 as a more aggressive form of lowercasing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing to do is put this in a loop and keep trying til they give acceptable input:

```
#... as before, then...
done = False

while done == False:

    x2=raw_input("Question 3" '\n'
        "How many tests have you taken in past 24 hours?" '\n'
        "A) 0" '\n'
        "B) 1" '\n'
        "C) 2" '\n'
        "D) 3" '\n'
        "E) Too many to count"'\n')


    if x2=="A":
       player_score.append('0')
       done = True
    elif x2=="B":
       player_score.append('1')
       done = True
    elif x2=="C":
       player_score.append('2')
       done = True
    elif x2=="D":
       player_score.append('3')
       done = True
    elif x2=="E":
       player_score.append('4')
       done = True
    else:
       print "you typed the wrong letter"
```

The repetition and boolean are a bit unpleasant, so could be refactored.

Comment: You could set `done=True` at the beginning of the while loop, then set `done=False` in your else block.